# Pan Gesture completion handler getting called immediately

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm animating a view to move as the user pans the screen. I have kept a threshold after which the view will animate to a default position.

The problem currently is that the completion handler of the animate method which resets the view to a position is called before the duration. The animation seems to be happening abruptly instead of over a duration of time.

```
// Pan gesture selector method
@objc func panAction(for panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch panGesture.state {
    case .began:
    //Began code
    case changed:
    if (condition) {
       print("IF")
       //Change constraint constant of customView
       animate(view: customView)
    } else if (condition) {
       print("ELSE IF")
       //Change constraint constant of customView
       animate(view: customView)
    } else {
       //Change constraint constant of customView
       print("ELSE")
       view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    case .ended:
    //Ended code
    default:
    break
    }
}
```

The animate method:

```
func animate(view: UIView) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { (finished) in
        if finished {
            flag = false
        }
    })
}
```

The flag is being set immediately rather than after 3 seconds.

The o/p i get while panning and crossing threshold.

ELSE

ELSE

ELSE

ELSE

IF

Edit: I am an idiot. I did not call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the superView.

Comment: Please add your code in question

Comment: I was editing my question. Please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. I was not calling `layoutIfNeeded` on the superview.

Answer (score 0):

Your gesture sends several events while the gesture is happening, and as you call your UIView.animate() code multiple times the new value supersedes the previous one.

Try adding the animation option `.beginFromCurrentState`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState,.allowAnimatedContent,.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}) { (completed) in
    ...
}
```

And expect your completed to be called multiple times with the completed == false as the gesture is progressing.

---

Edit: Your issue may also be related to calling layoutIfNeeded() on the wrong view, possibly try to call this on the viewController.view ?

Comment: I'm changing constants of anchors. I think they'll work fine even if i call them outside.

Comment: Even if the layout event is not associated with that particular view?

Comment: I just tried what you said. That doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: I understood exactly what you meant. That doesn't seem to the issue sir. Thanks for taking the time to explain though :)

Comment: @ekscypto Hey. I solved it. Seems like i had to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the superView of the view which i want updated. :(

Comment: Can you clear this one for me. What if i am doing 2 animations on 2 unrelated subViews of a superView and calling layoutIfNeeded would update both of them right? I only want one of them animated with duration.

Comment: That's where you need to figure out how to pass the changes you want done, so they are applied within the animation blocks like I was mentioning before